# apache openNLP chuker/POS noun detection

Tags: solr, nlp, opennlp, part-of-speech

I am experimenting apache Open NLP for one of my project, my requirement is to detect nouns out of email contents and check with our customer data base (this DB consist of individual names, organization names etc and my search engine is Solr base).

For normal english nouns, default trained model works properly (for most of the cases), but 
One of the tricky requirement is, we have business organization with abbreviations like OK, LET etc and thus in few scenarios I need to consider OK, LET etc as noun.

As an example
1) "sending some items to LET, please expect delay in payment"
2) "let us go for a party"

In #1 I want to consider LET as noun and in #2 case LET is not noun.

If I can achieve this requirement, I can reduce significant amount of false positive matches in my search engine.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just filter the bad ones out after processing?

Comment: my customer data is indexed in Solr and incoming email content is searched against indexes as free text search, customer data is changing daily....I am not sure whether I got your suggestion completely....but I want to build some rule like, after scanning only consider noun base hits (ignore non-noun base hits)

Comment: In your example, though, LET is still a noun.  You want it to be considered not a noun because it's capitalized?

Comment: It's definitely not case of letter, in my 1st example "sending some items to LET" means LET as an organization and thats why its noun here (if it could be small letters too meaning would be same), where as second one is "let us go for a party" where let is not noun...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a **dictionary** of the special nouns and perform dictionary-based extraction as a post-processing step. The dictionary-based extraction should take the distinction between lowercase and uppercase into account, in particular for those entries that are acronyms.

In terms of **implementation of the dictionary lookup:**

- As long as the entities in question are single tokens (or consist only of a predefined, small maximum number M of tokens each), implementing the dictionary as `HashSet<String>`, tokenising the text and making look-ups in the hash for each token (and groups of up to M tokens) should work very well
- If you are dealing with very long entities, or if tokenization is a problem, the use of a search trie or finite state machine implementation of the dictionary is sensible.

Finally, as always with NLP, you will need to **look at a significant sample of the results** to identify any further problems. Depending on the level of ambiguity in your entity list, you may need to further refine the detection method by adding either a heuristics or a statistical / ML-based decision mechanism on top of the case-sensitive dictionary look-up.

Comment: Thanks, but I think my main problem is not upper/lower case, problem is to consider meaning of "let" in various context (and similar to "let" I have many other terms).....I am still not sure how dictionary base approach will help here, but let me read some more details on dictionary and get back....Thanks again.

Comment: @Rushik I understand that you'd like to use a sophisticated approach that "understand" (whatever that means) the context and decides whether "let" is a verb or a proper noun based on that. But that is not only very complex, but also requires a lot of evaluation and refinement. The most straight-forward way to gain accuracy is to make use of the fact that the acronym will *most of the time* be uppercased, and the verb will not.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, I just tried standford version of NLP and as you mentioned, it is able to consider "LET" as noun and "let" as verb...but I am not getting same results with apache POS, may be I'll create dictionary as you suggested to achieve same...Thanks